# C++ propagate constructor update to client codebase

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17

So I am trying a add new feature to a legacy codebase. And want to do it with minimal impact to client codes.

I have a class with a default constructor and some non-default constructor too.

```
struct A {
   A() {}
   A(int x) {}
   A& operator+=(const A& other);
   std::array<int, 4> data;
};
```

previously class `A` had a static array of fixed size as a member. Now, with new requirement, the size of array is no longer fixed and has to be a dynamic array. The information of what should be the size, is stored in class `B`.
Now, with the new requirement, I have a add a required argument to all the constructor of class `A`.
e.g. class `A` will now look like below:

```
struct A {
   A(B *b) { size = b->getSize(); data = new int[size];}
   A(B *b, int x) { size = b->getSize(); data = new int[size]; }
   int *data;
};
```

The problem is, in the current client code, class `A` is instantiated at multiple places. (probably > 10,000 instances) and updating all places is not feasible.

Is there any C++ trick / pattern that can help me to propagate this change to client code seamlessly (or with minimal changes)
I am trying to think of a solution  but couldn't think of any.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you want `b` to be when the client calls the constructor without supplying a value for it?

Comment: I mean there are only 2 options: The client provides a value for `b` or you do it.

Comment: If you want `b` to be `nullptr` (or any other default) if the client doesn't supply it, you could make it the last parameter with a default value - e.g. `A(int x, B *b = nullptr) { ... }`.

Comment: This is what scripting is for. In the past when I had to do similar kind of refactoring and the wholesale replacement is feasible to be done programmatically, I simply whipped up a Perl script that chews on C++ source, and fed my entire git repo to it.

Comment: You can use search'n'replace. You can use dedicated refactoring tools. You could create a new class, deprecte the existing one and migrate the code step-by-step. You could theoretically also store a `B*` globally which you then use as a default, but that's something you don't want to do. In summary: There's no shortcut. That said, if you described why suddenly this new parameter is necessary and why in needs to be inserted in the front, that could perhaps result in a few better recommendations.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt previously class A had a static array of fixed size as a member. Now, with new requirement, the size of array is no longer fixed and has to be a dynamic array. The information of what should be the size, is stored in class B.

Comment: B * doesn;t need to be in the front

Comment: Still unclear, why not use a string and resize it according to what is needed? If at some point you need a fixed size, you can pad/truncate/filter/reject.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt edited my sample code with details. Does it make sense now?

Comment: If you have a valid default size (e.g. the fixed size that was used before), you can use it if `b` is `nullptr` which can serve as a default parameter value.

Comment: Yes, kind-of, though I'm still unsure about the background. As a side note, consider using a `vector<int>` instead of the raw pointer, but that's unrelated to the question here.

Comment: Pff..., this changes introduces an API compatibility break. This should be avoided whenever possible after an *official* release. For example, Microsoft uses `_ext` ending when a class is extended in a non compatible way, allowing both versions to coexist. Only a comment anyway, because depending on the context, doing the break ASAP is still the best way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `b` to be the last parameter of your contructors and give it a default value of `nullptr`.
Then if `b` is `nullptr` use the fixed size that was previously used.

This way the client can gradually upgrade to the enhanced API without the need to change the code all at once.

```
struct A {

    static constexpr size_t DEFAULT_SIZE = 4; // Use the previous fixed size

    A(B *b = nullptr)        { size = b ? b->getSize() : DEFAULT_SIZE; data = new int[size]; }
    A(int x, B *b = nullptr) { size = b ? b->getSize() : DEFAULT_SIZE; data = new int[size]; }

    // ...

    int *  data;
    size_t size;
};
```

A side note:
Instead of using a raw C array, it is recommended to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

---

**Update:**

You commented below that you would like `b->getSize()` to be the only source of size for the array.
Assuming all your `B` instances return the same size, you could create a `B` singleton, and use it as a default `b` instead of the `nullptr`:

```
#include <assert.h>

B* GetBSingleton()
{
    static B b;
    return &b;
}

struct A {

    A(B* b = GetBSingleton())        { assert(b); size = b->getSize(); data = new int[size]; }
    A(int x, B* b = GetBSingleton()) { assert(b); size = b->getSize(); data = new int[size]; }

    // ...

    int* data;
    size_t size;
};
```

Another option combines the 2 solutions:
Keep `nullptr` as a default value for `b`, but in case `b` is indeed  a `nullptr` get the size from `GetBSingleton()->getSize()` instead of `b->getSize()`.
The advantage here is that the header file is kept cleaner and the definition of `GetBSingleton()` can be pushed to the implementation file (.cpp).

Comment: The thing is, I want b->getSize() to be the single golden source of size. class `A` also has some operator + overloading and bad things will happen if `+` is called on objects of different sizes.

Comment: Not sure I understand. But assuming all your `B` instances return the same size, you can then make a `B` singleton, and use it as a default `b` parameter instead of the `nullptr`. This way the only source of size will be your `B` class. Will it help ?

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible solution with a `B` singelton.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know general size - instead of array, use std::vector. He have dynamic allocation by himself. Also, you can check the current count of members.
If you must to know the size - and get through class B - sorry to say, but you must change all instantiations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).